# how to get latest captured image from gallery in react-native (IOS)?

Tags: ios, react-native, camera-roll

After capturing the image, I am able to get the latest captured image in android but in IOS I am getting the last image in the gallery but not the latest captured image.

How can I get the latest captured image from gallery in IOS?

I am using

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
   first: 100,
   groupTypes: 'All',
   assetType: 'All'
})
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue? Please update. Thanks